# Strange Unicode behavior in xterm

Tags: zsh, unicode, xterm, utf-8

I recently switched my system from ISO-8859-15 to UTF-8 (I know I am a little late), works fine so far, I am just having a little issue with xterm and zsh.

When entering German - Umlaute (ä,ö,ü) and pressing backspace to remove them afterwards, there are 2 symbols removed (even if these symbols belong to the prompt itself).

My locale is de_DE.UTF8, any suggestions?

Comment: What's your OS / Distro? Is it working as expected using another terminal emular + zsh and xterm + bash, resp.?

Comment: gentoo testing, rxvt works as expected,
using finch inside xterm works as expected too....

Comment: Is zsh compiled with `--enable-multibyte`?

Comment: And what's the output of `bindkey | grep '\^H'`?

Comment: Found the error, thanks for your time, the fault was created by me. For some reason I added zsh -unicode to my package.use directory.

Comment: Glad to hear that you could identify the problem. I'm not sure if ypu need some minimal reputation to do so, but in principle you can write an answer to your own question. So, if you could elaborate a little on your solution, that might help future visitors of the question. `:)`